# How to use hibernate cache in different app with the same database?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I have 2 applications, which using the same database. The first app can write and read from database. The second app only read from database.
I include second-level hibernate cache with read-write strategy. And now, when I change data from the first app, I don't see this changes at the second app.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not an hibernate expert, maybe somebody else can give a more cripsy answer...

This is the same question on SO:
[Hibernate 2nd level cache invalidation when another process modifies the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603846/hibernate-2nd-level-cache-invalidation-when-another-process-modifies-the-databas) However it seems fairly outdated.

You need to look for a distributed or replicated cache and follow the documentation of the respective product. Examples:

- [Using Infinispan as JPA second level cache provider](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_jpa_hibernate_second_level_cache_provider)
- [Using EHCache and hibernate](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-hib_using_ehcache_with_hibernate.html%23)

Some blog articles about it:

- http://codespot.net/2014/02/03/hibernate-caching-strategies
- http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries

If one application directly writes to the database you need to properly invalidate the second level caches by yourself.